# Are there libraries to search Amazon CloudSearch from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

What libraries are out there to perform searches in AWS' CloudSearch domains? The AWS SDK is virtually devoid of search capabilities.

---

I would like to use Amazon CloudSearch for a project to search in pre-existing databases for certain customer-related data for billing purposes.

We already have extensive experience with Solr-based search services, but in this particular instance we do not want to host the search service in-house and already have experience with AWS.

The Amazon SDK provides a decent .NET-based approach to administer search domains. But: Apparrently it lacks any capability whatsoever to actually **search** for things.

I have found [a few](https://github.com/Bigjono/AWS-CloudSearch) [attempts](https://github.com/breaker05/Amazon-CloudSearch) to provide a search API, but nothing that works OOTB. Any suggestions or experience with CloudSearch from within .NET?

(Yes, I know it is easy to just chug parameters in a web service call and deal with the JSON reply; a wrapper / library just would deal better with the messy details of parsing etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly the AWS .NET SDK includes support for CloudSearch now: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/1600390926978863

Comment: The .NET SDK got support for the 2013-01-01 library in 2.0.13.  See https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/9771944499314081

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a library in C# on github, you can use.
 https://github.com/martin-magakian/Amazing-Cloud-Search

It's "just" a wrapper, but part of the challenge was to match the JSON to the object you are working with (generic). Because Amazon cloud search is always working with array of string or array of uint but I still wanted my library to match the object properties whever it is an array or not.

It wasn't as easy as expected I share my work so more of us can play with Amazon Cloud Search.

Martin Magakian

Comment: Just a comment from the future, if you're using the 2013-01-01 version of CloudSearch this library didn't have support at this point in time

Answer (score 1):

Like [@martin-magakian's Amazing-Cloud-Search library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118365/1037948) for v1 (which works great, by the way), you could use the Comb wrapper for v2: https://github.com/BarryDahlberg/Comb.